# Can we use class transitions in jQuery like with CSS3?

Tags: jquery, class, css, jquery-animate, transition

Do any of you know the answer to the following problem. It's driving me crazy that I cannot find a solution.

I want to animate in jQuery by adding/replacing a class and transitioning between the two, NOT by using inline styling.

This is exactly how CSS3 transition works, and its really great and allows for quick prototyping. But I want to do it in jQuery because I want it to be normalised across all browsers.

I've used jQuery animate for a long time, but I've only used it to add inline-styling. This gets really messy to manage and means I can't have the end result written in CSS and separate the presentation layer from the logic.

Consider the following example. In CSS3 if I want to animate a div height by changing the height of a div I can do this:

1. A div has a class .object which has an initial height of 100px.
2. An event runs, and the div now has the classes .object and .active.
3. With the .active class, the CSS now sets the height to 150px
4. Using CSS3 transition, I can allow a smooth transition between the two over 2 seconds with easing.

If i want to do the same thing in jQuery:

1. A div has a class .object which has an initial height of 100px.
2. An event runs, and I use .animate to animate the height of the object to 150px
3. As a result of this, the CSS now sets the height to 150px using inline styling
4. Using parameters I can set the speed in ms with easing.

You may be aware of jQuery UI which allows transition on toggleClass and switchClass:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/

However, annoyingly it won't work for the example above because it only works if the initial class has no specific height set. To test this, inspect the element in the demo and give it a height and watch the demo break.

Hopefully someone can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You could try DOM Mutation Events, which are dispatched eg. when a property of an element is changed.

There are plugins for jQuery, which mimes the behavior of event mutation (although I haven't tried any of those).

But feel free to google about mutation events in jQuery and that should probably help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/

(i made a similar question few weeks a go [can a .classA styles to .classB styles be animated easly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023575/can-a-classa-styles-to-classb-styles-be-animated-easly) )

Comment: I acknowledged this in the question - What if you want to keep the old class and add a new class? NOT switch. For example, I might want .object to keep the width and background colour and .active .object to change the height. I'm pretty sure it won't work.

Comment: what browser support do you need?

Comment: yeah, so i don't think this fits for you. you could have double clases (.class1{}; .class2{} and then .class1.class2{}) but IE7 won't take them

Comment: .class.class is not supported in IE7, but .class .class is. This can be enough to override a style.

You are missing the point, we are talking semantics here and not answering the question. I want to be able to have a transition between a CSS change.

Comment: well i am sorry that i can't be more helpfull... i can provide you a solution to work with css3; sorry i don't see a trivial solution for IE that i am willing to program for this question

Comment: I'm sorry but I think we misunderstand each other. This is not just a trivial solution to IE. Selecting classes that inherit each other (i.e .class .class) is fundamental to all browsers and the switch method only works (as far as I am aware) for when you replace classes.